# Converting CSV to TDV - Formatting issues

Tags: python

I am working on creating a tab delimited file out of certain values from a CSV file. The CSV file contains all of the orders placed in the last month and I need to format it correctly to be able to import into the accounting software currently being used. Here is a sample of the data from the CSV file:

```
Customer    Order Number    Item Line Number    Quantity    Product Description

cust1       Order #1                1               40              desc1
cust1       Order #2                1               101             desc2
cust2       Order #3                1               3               desc3
cust2       Order #3                2               8               desc3
cust2       Order #3                3               8               desc3
cust1       Order #4                1               75              desc4
```

Now, for each series of `Order Number` I need to create a section of the TDV file that looks something like this: (Ignore the parenthesis, these are just to show where the values come from above)

```
1       cust1           HA5ZV1          Desc1           Due Date        ...
2       1 (Item #)      40 (Qty)        ...             ...             ...

1       cust1           HA6A17          Desc2           Due Date        ...
2       1 (Item #)      101 (Qty)       ...             ...             ...

1       cust2           HA6AM1          Desc3           Due Date        ...
2       1 (Item #)      3 (Qty)         ...             ...             ...
2       2 (Item #)      8 (Qty)         ...             ...             ...
2       3 (Item #)      8 (Qty)         ...             ...             ...
```

Hopefully this makes sense. What I have done so far is create a dictionary out of the original CSV file, but am confused as to how to loop through my dictionary(s) and write the header (lines marked with a "1") once, then write the values (lines marked with a "2") for every time the same `Order Number` appears. Here is my code so far:

```
data = csv.reader(open(import_dir))
fields = data.next()
new_file = export_dir+os.path.basename(import_dir)
tab_file = open(export_dir+os.path.basename(import_dir), 'a+')
for row in data:
    items = zip(fields, row)
    item = {}
    for (name, value) in items:
        item[name] = value.strip()
    tab_file.write('1\t'+item['Customer']+'\t'+item['Order Number']+'\t'
                   +item['Product Description']+'\t'+item['Due Date']+'\n'+
                   '2\t'+item['Item Line Number']+'\t'+item['Quantity']+'\t'+
                   ...
```

But this code puts the header data before each line item, rather than placing it only in the beginning of each order. If every customer only ordered one item, that would be fine, but since some orders have multiple line items, it screws up the formatting. If anybody can point me in the right direction that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Use `csv.writer(tab_file, delimiter='\t')` and it'll write TSV files..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the [`itertools.groupby()` tool](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group your input lines by customer number:

```
import csv
import os
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

new_file = os.path.join(export_dir, os.path.basename(import_dir))

with open(import_dir) as import, open(new_file, 'ab') as tab_file:
    data = csv.reader(import)
    writer = csv.writer(tab_file, delimiter='\t')

    fields = next(data)
    for customer, rows in groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0)):
        first_row = next(rows)
        item = {f: v.strip() for f, v in zip(fields, first_row)}
        writer.writerow([1, customer, item['Order Number'], item['Product Description'], item['Due Date'])
        writer.writerow([2, item['Item Line Number'], item['Quantity'], ...])
        for i, row in enumerate(rows, 3):
            item = {f: v.strip() for f, v in zip(fields, row)}
            writer.writerow([i, item['Item Line Number'], item['Quantity'], ...])
```

`groupby()` returns the current result of the `key` function, and an iterable of all rows that have that key value. As soon as the next row no longer has the same key, a new group is started.

Other things I changed:

- Use `with` to have your open files closed automatically, regardless of what else happens.
- Use `os.path.join()` to build paths
- Use `csv.writer(..., delimiter='\t')` to write tab-separated files; it is just another CSV dialect, really.
- I used a dict comprehension to turn your rows into dictionaries. Alternatively, just use `csv.DictReader()` to do the same thing; no need to read the fields from the first row.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Just did some preliminary testing and it looks like it's working well.

Comment: Thank you for helping clean it up as well.